# Universe is a cluster of orbiting Galaxies?

Tags: galaxy, observable-universe

Like planets orbiting stars, solar systems and other celestial objects orbiting a blackhole in the center of a galaxy, are the Galaxies and Galaxy clusters orbiting the centre of a universe (for example : let's say the largest blackhole of the universe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few things to unpick here. Clusters or groups of galaxies are tiny compared to the size of the observable universe, and while gravity acts upon all bodies, in reality the distances between galaxies mean that effect is minimal.

And as the universe is expanding, tangential velocities are insignificant, so no, galaxies are not orbiting the centre of the universe.

And the centre of the universe is undefined - there is no "largest blackhole" to be the centre.

Even where you have two galaxies coming relatively close to each other (cf [Andromeda and Milky Way colliding in about 4 billion years](https://www.britannica.com/video/186502/overview-collision-galaxies-Milky-Way-Andromeda)) the effects are so localised that until collision has happened, you wouldn't say that any of the stars in each of the galaxies is orbiting their common centre.